# Is the single-quote the only character in PL/SQL text literals that needs escaping assuming LIKE clauses are not being used?

Tags: sql, plsql, escaping, special-characters, sql-injection

I have a script that generates a large bulk of update statements. Those statements will be executed by being copied and pasted into SQL Developer by a human without validation.

To avoid accidental SQL injection, I tried to understand more about special characters. Based on the resources I found so far, I'm starting to believe that if LIKE clauses are not being used, then it's only the single-quote that needs to be escaped. This contradicts my spidey sense, which states that escaping special characters must be more complicated than that, so I decided to post this question for validation.

Comment: You should also give special attention to `&`. Replace it with `chr(38)` with concatanation

Comment: @Popeye, I tried to run `UPDATE usr SET some_attr = '&' WHERE usr_key = '1';` now and it seems to have put an ampersand in that field. Are there specific type of statements where it may cause an issue?

Comment: If it is part of the string then the underscore (_) also needs to be escaped.  It not then it is a single character wildcard.